# Collapse Data Explorer queries to only show latest revision

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

If you've used Data Explorer's search, you've probably been greeted with results like this:

[image]

Lots and lots of the same exact query as separate results! They're actually revisions of the same query, forks that have the exact same title but they're not collapsed.

Could they be collapsed to only show the latest (and most likely useful) version of the query with the *same exact title*, maybe with some sort of "history" on the page to show all the other forks? Forks aren't always just "the latest copy"...but forks with the *exact same title* almost certainly are. And if your fork *is* a different query, not just an updated one...please rename your query!

Comment: Yes...this is a bit of a two-fold problem. Not only is there duplication in the results, but people are creating multiple forks of the same query (which they probably didn't really want in most cases, they just wanted a new revision of their own fork).

Comment: @TimStone If that's a thing you can do we should certainly encourage it...I haven't made queries though, I'm only familiar with looking for them, which is a pain :P

Comment: Yeah, waffles and I talked about this before. I'll see what I can do about addressing that and making the search results a little more useful. I've got several other things I'm working on at the moment though, so I probably won't get to it until next week.