# Why is query name not unique in Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

When I searched for the query *"How Unsung am I?"*. I got plenty of records (122) having this query name. Why is Data Explorer not imposing unique constraint in query names?

Comment: Seems to be the same base query edited/forked by different users

Comment: @Old is correct, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134928/152859). I would place a bounty there but I'm out of bounties for now. :(